# Do crystals crushed by falling blocks count towards the "break 10 crystals" objective?

Tags: unidentified-falling-objects

On world 5 there is an objective to "Break 10 crystals". Do crystals crushed by falling blocks count towards the objective, or does it only count blocks you've shot and destroyed yourself?

[image: Break 10 crystals objective]